# terraform returns 500 error when whitelisting IPs in Mongo Atlas

Tags: terraform, mongodb-atlas

When I try to whitelist IPs via terraform in Mongo Atlas, I get the below error intermittently;

`mongodbatlas_project_ip_whitelist.test[2`]:

1 error(s) occurred:

`mongodbatlas_project_ip_whitelist.test.2: error creating project IP whitelist`:

POST https://cloud.mongodb.com/api/atlas/v1.0/groups/5e4652ed55385542bbfeb88c/whitelist:

```
 500 (request "Internal Server Error") Unexpected error.

mongodbatlas_project_ip_whitelist.test[0]: 1 error(s) occurred:

mongodbatlas_project_ip_whitelist.test.0: error creating project IP whitelist
```

POST

https://cloud.mongodb.com/api/atlas/v1.0/groups/5e4652ed55385542bbfeb88c/whitelist

```
500 (request "Internal Server Error") Unexpected error.
```

The terraform script I used:

```
resource "mongodbatlas_project_ip_whitelist" "mongo_whitelist" {   
   project_id = "${var.mongo_projectkey}"   
   count = "${length(var.mongo_atlas_inbound_whitelist)}"   
   cidr_block = "${var.mongo_atlas_inbound_whitelist[count.index]}" 
}
```

Any idea please?

Comment: Have you tried enabling debug output to see if you can get more information?

    export TF_LOG=DEBUG

https://www.terraform.io/docs/internals/debugging.html

Comment: Thanks, @AndrewSnell for looking into it. Yes, I was able to enable the debug log and find the following.

Comment: Right details were sent to Mongo via their API and the response was saying it was an internal server error. As I answered myself below, it was fixed with their new release.

Answer (score 0):

Seems this is a bug in 0.3.1 Terraform MongoDB Atlas Provider when count meta-parameter is used.

It seems fixed in the version 0.4.0 of the MongoDB Atlas Terraform provider, which contains a number of other changes too to the mongodbatlas_project_ip_whitelist resource.

I just upgraded the version from 0.3.1 to 0.4.0:

```
terraform init -upgrade=true
```

This sorted out the issue.